# Portrayal of police in Korean cinema

Tags: analysis, character, korean-cinema

Why is the police shown as bunch of jokers in the Korean cinema? In almost all Korean movies which I have seen, the cops are portrayed as stupid fools, apart from the protagonist in cases where he is a cop? Has anyone else felt the same about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may date back to the era of [The Keystone Cops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_Cops).  As I recall from a Film class I took in college, one of the tenants of early comedic cinema was "to mock authority".  Putting an authority figure (policeman) in a situation where he appears to be a bumbling idiot was a great way to elicit laughs in the early days.  While the technique is still widely used, it rarely gets a good laugh from today's moviegoers.